# How do I find the boundary of a boundary of a boundary of a set?

Tags: general-topology

So I'm trying to wrap my head around basic topology, and I've been given this task to prove that
$$\partial(\partial(\partial A)) = \partial(\partial A)$$

Where $A \subseteq X $ and X is a topological space. How should I prove this and is it even a thing?

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this result cannot be weakened as e.g. for $A= \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ we have $\partial(\partial(A)) = \partial([0,1]) = \{0,1\} \neq [0,1] = \partial(A)$.

Comment: @G. Chiusole: FYI, this property of the boundary operator came up in [sci.math back in 2001-2002](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/PdqIT_VuHVM/aFeIIxLm4FcJ) (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/PdqIT_VuHVM/o-sI6i4KK_AJ) also).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since $\partial B=\overline{B}\setminus Int(B)$, we have that $\partial B$ is closed for any $B$, and thus $\partial(\partial(\partial(A))=\partial(\partial A)\setminus Int(\partial(\partial(A)),$ so the statement is that $Int(\partial(\partial(A))=\emptyset$.

Let $x\in \partial(\partial A))$ and let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$. Then, by definition, $U\cap\partial A\neq \emptyset$ and $U\cap (X\setminus \partial A)\neq \emptyset$. Reapplying the above, since $\partial A$ is closed, we have $\partial(\partial A)\subseteq \partial A$. Thus, we see that $U\cap (X\setminus \partial(\partial A))\neq \emptyset$. In conclusion, $x\not \in Int(\partial(\partial A))$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $Int(\partial (\partial(A))=\emptyset$.

Note that we really proved the stronger statement that $\partial(\partial C)=\partial C$ for any closed $C$.